# carousel controls are overlapping with navbar option in small screen making navbar accessing impossible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am having navbar and carousel created with bootstrap (v3.3.5)

I have created JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/x6ktq8oc/3/) but over there code seems to work fine. But on chrome and IE9 navbar is overlapped by carousel controls, which makes accessing links on the page impossible as it keeps redirecting to images in the carousel.

Then I added css as follow:

```
.carousel-control.left
{
margin-top:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
max-height:80%;
}
.carousel-control.right 
{
margin-top:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
max-height:80%;
}
```

Now I can access the links correctly on larger screen but on shorter screen, after expanding icon bar (hamburg icon) carousel controls remain on navbar rather than around images (slider).

How to shift carousel controls next to carousel from navbar?

Here are attached screenshots[image: Screenshots showing problem]

Answer (score 1):

Have you messed around with the z-index? There is already a z-index in bootstrap.min.css...

```
.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right                 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Try...

```
.carousel-control{
    z-index:4 !important;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    z-index:6 !important;
}
```

This may not be exactly right but is worth fiddling with. Try add !important to the css if it doesn't work, and make sure that the z-index position doesn't conflict with other z-indexing on the site.

Comment: No I haven't changed Z-index. Only changes in CSS (related to carousel) are 
.carousel-inner > .item > img {

    margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel-control.left
{
margin-top:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
max-height:83%;
}
.carousel-control.right 
{
margin-top:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
max-height:83%;
}

And the changes you suggested are not working any way :(